# Bind (screen)-framebuffer to texture

Tags: opengl, rendering

How can I catch/copy/grab the currently displayed screen in OpenGL and read it into a GLuint Texture for using it in the next frame again as Texture ?

```
// Set random seed
program.setUniformValue("seed", ((float)qrand()/RAND_MAX));

//Set number of alredy rendered passes
program.setUniformValue("numRenderPass",mRenderPasses);

//Bind last rendered Image
//pixelsRenderedImage = bindTexture(*renderedImage);

//Load Identity
glLoadIdentity();

//Move to rendering point
glTranslatef( -1.0, -1.0, 0.0f );

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pixelsScene);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pixelsRenderedImage);

// Draw geometry
//Render textured quad
glBegin( GL_QUADS );
    glTexCoord2f( 0.f, 0.f ); glVertex2f( 0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f( 1.f, 0.f ); glVertex2f( 2.0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f( 1.f, 1.f ); glVertex2f( 2.0, 2.0);
    glTexCoord2f( 0.f, 1.f ); glVertex2f( 0, 2.0);
 glEnd();

 //PseudoCode
 Read_Back_screen_to -> pixelsRenderedImage
```

I want to bypass glReadPixels (the CPU) to speed up rendering "a little" ;-).

Comment: In what way do you think this question shall be tagged with `qt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glCopyTexImage2D()` ([man page](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glCopyTexImage2D.xml)) is the call you're looking for. It is used to copy data from the current framebuffer into a texture.

I don't think this call Is used much anymore. The preferred approach for cases where you want to use the result of rendering as texture content are Framebuffer Objects (FBO). They allow you to render to textures directly, avoiding an extra copy operation. FBO support was introduced in OpenGL 3.0.

Comment: Also the contents of the on-screen framebuffer may be undefined at any time. In general it's very unreliable to grab images from the on-screen framebuffers and reuse them for further rendering steps. Use a FBO instead.